# How to link against a target found by find_package() in a sibling CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake, hierarchy, siblings, find-package

I have a hierarchy like this:

```
CMakeLists.txt        # calls add_subdirectory() for subdirs in the listed order
+-deps
| +-CMakeLists.txt    # calls find_package(Vulkan), a 3rd party lib, present on my system
+-mylib
| +-CMakeLists.txt    # depends on Vulkan::Vulkan
| +-mylib.cpp
+-example
  +-CMakeLists.txt    # depends on Vulkan::Vulkan
  +-example.cpp
```

The problem is that in mylib/CMakeLists.txt and example/CMakeLists.txt for the following command:

`target_link_libraries(mylib PRIVATE Vulkan::Vulkan)`

I got the following error:

```
CMake Error at mylib/CMakeLists.txt:2 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "mylib" links to:

    Vulkan::Vulkan

  but the target was not found. Possible reasons include:

    * There is a typo in the target name.
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
    * An ALIAS target is missing.
```

And the same goes for example/CMakeLists.txt.

**My question:**
How can I make those CMakeLists.txt files see the targets found by find_package() in their sibling CMakeLists.txt files?

**What I tried:**
I moved the `find_package()` to the root CMakeLists.txt, and then everything worked. But I want to neatly organize my files. This is a strongly simplified version. The real hierarchy is much more complicated.

I found `set(PARENT_SCOPE)` and was able to propagate the `TRUE` value of `${Vulkan_FOUND}` from deps to root and then to example. Maybe something similar is needed but for targets instead of variables?

**Details:**

./CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6...3.22)

project(mylib VERSION 0.0.1)

add_subdirectory(deps)
add_subdirectory(mylib)
add_subdirectory(example)
```

./deps/CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Vulkan)
```

./mylib/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(mylib mylib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC Vulkan::Vulkan)
```

./example/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example PUBLIC mylib Vulkan::Vulkan)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CMake `find_package` usage is expected to be **local** to the directory and its descendants. If some other directory (from other hierarchy) needs the same package, then it should repeat `find_package` call.

Concerning specifically "deps" functionality, I saw many projects which move this functionality into a separate `.cmake` script, and include that script via `include()` command in the root `CMakeLists.txt`. Wherever the included `.cmake` script is located, the `include` command does NOT introduce a directory scope.
So, every `find_package` call from that script is scoped to the root `CMakeLists.txt`, so its results can be used in any subdirectory.

`./cmake/deps.cmake`:

```
find_package(Vulkan)
```

`./CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6...3.22)

project(mylib VERSION 0.0.1)

# Specify directory where included scripts will be searched.
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

include(deps)

add_subdirectory(mylib)
add_subdirectory(example)
```